# Grails where is the instance updated between "create" and "save"

Tags: grails

I'm wondering, in the scaffold controller and views, how the fields you fill in the "create" page get updated to your domain class instance before the save action. I'm on Grails 2.4.4.

Take an example, I have one class called Customer and I generate the controller and views all in the default way.

```
class Customer {
    String name;
    String email;
    String address;
    String mobile;
}
```

And when you run the application and in the generated green-styled index page, click on "create new customer", one Customer instance will be created as the link goes to "create" action.

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="default.home.label"/></a></li>
    <li><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="default.new.label" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
</ul>
```

In controller:

```
def create() {
    log.info "A customer object is created here.";
    Customer c=new Customer(params)
    respond c
}
```

**But now you haven't filled in the form on all the fields yet!** And after you fill in the form in create.gsp, the link will point you directly to "save" action.

```
<g:form url="[resource:customerInstance, action:'save']" >
    <fieldset class="form">
        <g:render template="form"/>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="buttons">
        <g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" />
    </fieldset>
</g:form>
```

But in the save action I see nothing related to setting the fields on this instance as the form goes. **Where is it done?**

```
@Transactional
def save(Customer customerInstance) {
    if (customerInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }
    if (customerInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond customerInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }
    customerInstance.save flush:true
    //omit everything after save here
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grails does this for you automatically with [Data Binding](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/single.html#dataBinding). Grails controllers can take two categories of arguments: basic objects, and complex objects. The default behavior is to map HTTP request parameters to action arguments by name, wherever applicable. For example, say we have a controller like so:

```
def doSomething(Integer magicNumber) {
    println "The magic number is $magicNumber"
}
```

and a view that contains a field like this:

```
<g:textField name="magicNumber" value="${magicNumber}" />
```

When the form is submitted to the `doSomething` action, Grails will automatically take the `magicNumber` request param, convert it from a String to an Integer and pass it to the action.

Complex types (like domain objects) are treated as [command objects](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/single.html#commandObjects). Command objects function in a similar manner to basic objects in regards to data binding. Notice how in your code, the save action takes a `Customer` instance as an argument? Behind the scenes, Grails takes the HTTP request parameters and binds those parameters to the properties of a given object, in this case, a `Customer`. From the documentation:

> Before the controller action is executed Grails will automatically create an instance of the command object class and populate its properties by binding the request parameters.

In other words, Grails will look at all of the incoming request parameters and attempt to bind those to properties on the object that you've stated as an argument to the action. In addition, it will perform validation for you. It's essentially the same as:

```
@Transactional
def save() {
    Customer customerInstance = new Customer(params)
    customerInstance.validate()

    if (customerInstance == null) {
        notFound()
        return
    }
    if (customerInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond customerInstance.errors, view:'create'
        return
    }
    customerInstance.save flush:true
    //omit everything after save here
}
```

Comment: EXACTLY the answer i'm looking for! Thank you!